# Changing background image through window.getComputedStyle

Tags: css, background-image, getcomputedstyle

I'm trying to write a function which cycles `background-image` from 3 different options by button-click, and the code is not working. Maybe someone can tell why...

```
function changeBackground (){
  console.log('change background');
  var b = document.getElementById('mainbody');
  var bstyle = window.getComputedStyle(b, null).getPropertyValue('background-image');
  if (bstyle == "url('strawberry.png')") {
    b.style.backgroundImage = "url('raspberry.png')";
  } else if (bstyle == "url('raspberry.png')"){
    b.style.backgroundImage = "url('blueberry.png')";
  } else {
    b.style.backgroundImage = "url('strawberry.png')";
  }
}
```

For example, this code for changing `font-size` works perfectly.

```
function changeSize (){ 
  console.log('changing font size');
  var s = document.getElementById('clock');
  var sstyle = window.getComputedStyle(s, null).getPropertyValue('font-size');
  if (sstyle == "25px") {
    s.style.fontSize = "50px";
  } else{
    s.style.fontSize = "25px";
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the variable `s`? Why is `bstyle` not set to `b.style.backgroundImage`? This is hard to understand without context.

Comment: @StardustGogeta Of course, there should be variable  `b`.

Comment: After fixing the typo, does the problem persist? If not, this question can be deleted.

Comment: @StardustGogeta the problem still persist

Comment: I think I figured it out. The filepath is converted to an absolute path (rather than relative) when it is computed as CSS, making the comparisons largely useless. I would suggest, then, simply making a counter variable to see how many times the function is called and taking the remainder modulo 3.

Comment: @StardustGogeta `<button id="change-image">BACKGOUND</button>`. Then I use `let changeBackgroundButton;` to make a variable.  Then there is this code in "init" function `changeBackgroundButton = document.querySelector('#change-image');
  changeBackgroundButton.addEventListener('click', changeBackground);`. And "init" function works with `window.onload`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var x = 0;
var pics = ['strawberry.png', 'raspberry.png', 'blueberry.png'];
function changeBackground (){
  console.log('change background');
  var b = document.getElementById('mainbody');
  b.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+pics[(x++) % pics.length]+')';
}
```

I would suggest using a counter variable, as shown above, in order to track the number of times the function is called and update the background accordingly.

The problem that is being experienced is that when JavaScript changes the background image URL, the full absolute path is saved as the computed value in CSS. However, when comparing against it later, this absolute path does not match the relative one that was initially used. Clearly, other attributes, such as `font-size`, would not experience this same issue.

Comment: Thank you very much. This was very helpful.